# How to encode NSMutableData

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-bluetooth

I have a code below to draw a content of html page to PDF in my swift class

```
let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: htmlContent)
    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)
    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 384, height: 6741) // 58mm
    render.setValue(page, forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(page, forKey: "printableRect")
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, page, nil)
    for i in 0..<render.numberOfPages {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        render.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

then I passed `pdfData` variable to obj-c class to print out by my bluetooth printer via example code

```
[_bleGattService write:[_TextField.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] withResponse:withResponse];
```

I have tried to replace `_TextField.text` to `pdfData` or even convert `pdfData` to String type but no luck. I'm a newest with this, pls help!!!

Comment: `pdfData` is a `NSMutableData`, so just do `[_bleGattService write:pdfData withResponse:withResponse];`

Comment: @Larme then the printer prints out alien language. I think we should encode it somehow first!

Comment: Can your printer accept PDF? On this characteristic ? On another one? Do you need to tell before hand that you're going to pass a pdf, and not raw text? Because it's printing raw text. So what you want is even possible? PDF/HTML embed text and add a rendering, do you want to print that render, or only text?

Comment: printer saler send me that example code without any explaination. As you can see, that example for raw text printing. I am writing a receipt app which will display content on webview of a View Controller, what I need is print out exactly what I see on that webview. The saler has the sam app (but it has too many redundant features), that means printing out HTML content is possible.

Comment: Without knowing the doc (or even model, list of services/characteristics) we can't guess, you have to reverse engineer. Ask the saler?

Comment: it's a custom printer from something I do not determine. The doc is written by Chinese. Maybe I should ask the saler or beg him.

Comment: @Larme I looked for its version. It's a Portable Wireless BT 58mm Thermal Receipt Printer.